# how to convert a big int to a double in C++

Tags: c++, type-conversion, biginteger, ttmath

In C++, I want to get the square root of a big int. The number is less than the maximum integer represented as a double, so this approach should work. The ttmath library doesn't have a square root function.

I'm using the ttmath library for big ints.

I wrote the following program:

```
#include <ttmath/ttmath.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ttmath::UInt<4>  a = "234567890123456789012345";

    // convert BigInt to double
    double d=(double)a;

    // then take the square root of the double
    double b = sqrt(d);

    cout << b << endl;
}
```

Compiling it results in the following error the following error:

```
cannot convert 'ttmath::UInt<3>' to 'double' without a conversion operator
    double d=(double)a;
```

So it doesn't like using a cast for converting to a double.

What is the required conversion operator?

Comment: When using big number libraries, don't using casting.  Use one of the library functions for converting between Big Number and `double`.  The two may not have compatible layouts (like 32-bits), so the cast won't work.

Comment: You say the number is less than the largest integer representable by a double, but then you show a 24-digit value. The largest integer that can be represented in a double with full precision is about 2^52, which amounts to about 16 digits in base-10. So, right out of the gate you are going to have a loss of precision. You may want to consider the Newton-Raphson method to find the square root with full precision using elementary operations in this `ttmath` library.

Comment: *The ttmath library doesn't have a square root function.* -- [Are you sure?](https://gitea.ttmath.org/tomasz.sowa/ttmath/src/commit/aad580f51e7ffc32966507a9897ec575c389e3e6/ttmath/ttmath.h#L1848)

Answer (score 2):

The ttmath library doesn't directly allow converting `Int` or `UInt` to `double`.
You need to go through `ttmath::Big`

```cpp
ttmath::UInt<4> a = "234567890123456789012345";

// 12 (signed) exponent bits, 52 mantissa bits;
// that's all we need for converting to double precision, assuming binary64 representation
ttmath::Big<12, 52> big = a;
double d = big.ToDouble();
```

That being said, you don't need to convert to `double` to compute the square root or print.

```cpp
ttmath::Big<12, 52> big = a;
big.Sqrt();
std::cout << big;
```

You can also compute the integer square root with `a.Sqrt()`, but this wouldn't give you any fractional digits.